# How does "new IClasspathEntry[0]" work?

Tags: java, interface, new-operator

I have this code from [Java project helper](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.tests/test-plugin/org/eclipse/jdt/debug/testplugin/JavaProjectHelper.java.shtml).

```
javaProject.setRawClasspath(new IClasspathEntry[0], null);
```

How `new IClasspathEntry[0]` works?

[image]

1. How an interface is instantiated with new?
2. How an array `[0]` is used instead of parenthesis `()` with new?

### ADDED

I think it's a safer way of saying null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How an interface is instantiated with new?

No, an Interface can never be instantiated.

> 2.How an array [0] is used instead of parenthesis () with new?

`IClasspathEntry[0]` is just an element of type `IClasspathEntry(well, asubtype of IClasspathEntry)` at index zero in your array. you can't instantiate an interface.

```
IClasspathEntry[] arr = new IClasspathEntry[size];
```

The above just creates an **array** of type `IClasspathEntry` which accepts `subtypes(class's which implement IClasspathEntry)` elements.

### Sample Code :

```
interface IClasspathEntry {}

class Xyz implements IClasspathEntry {}

class main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        IClasspathEntry[] arr = new IClasspathEntry[1];
        IClasspathEntry inst = new Xyz();
        arr[0] = inst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How an interface is instantiated with new?

`new IClasspathEntry[0]` is creating an `array object` and not instantiating your interface.
Just like `new int[4]` does not instantiate the primitive int type, but creates an array object of length 4.

> How an array [0] is used instead of parenthesis () with new?

It is valid as it is creating an array - a 0-length array.

You create an array like this so that you can add multiple instances of different implementing classes added to it.

```
IClasspathEntry[] arr = new IClasspathEntry[2];
arr[0] = // instance of class implementing IClasspathEntry
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with empty arrays, just like there's nothing wrong with empty collections. Better than `null` IMHO.

Comment: @PaulBellora. Yeah that is true. Might be useful when returning from some method.